Unable to write to a newly created file on Dropbox
I'm using ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument() to allow users to pick a destination for a file I need to save and then I'm using this kind of code to write data to the file identified by the uri that I get:
try (OutputStream os = mContext.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(fileUri)) {
    if (os == null) {
        // This happens for uris from Dropbox
        ...
        return;
    }
    // proceed with writing data
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
}

It works fine except when I select a Dropbox dir as a destination. For Dropbox an empty file is created, but the output stream that I get from content resolver is null.
In logs I can see this message (coming from Dropbox, not my app):
2024-04-03 17:14:14.586 27059-27073 JavaBinder              com.dropbox.android                  E  *** Uncaught remote exception! Exceptions are not yet supported across processes. Client PID 26395 UID 10806.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.dropbox.product.dbapp.metadata.exceptions.PathDoesNotExistException
    at android.os.Parcel.writeException(Parcel.java:2854)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.writeExceptionToParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:117)
    at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:439)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1375)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1311)
Caused by: com.dropbox.product.dbapp.metadata.exceptions.PathDoesNotExistException
    at dbxyzptlk.kw0.z.L(RealMetadataManager.java:20)
    at dbxyzptlk.kw0.z.l(RealMetadataManager.java:3)
    at dbxyzptlk.lm0.v.u(DropboxDocumentProviderDelegate.kt:123)
    at com.dropbox.product.android.dbapp.document_provider.DropboxDocumentProvider$d.b(DropboxDocumentProvider.kt:13)
    at com.dropbox.product.android.dbapp.document_provider.DropboxDocumentProvider$d.invoke(DropboxDocumentProvider.kt:1)
    at com.dropbox.product.android.dbapp.document_provider.DropboxDocumentProvider.b(DropboxDocumentProvider.kt:1)
    at com.dropbox.product.android.dbapp.document_provider.DropboxDocumentProvider.openDocument(DropboxDocumentProvider.kt:34)
    at android.provider.DocumentsProvider.openAssetFile(DocumentsProvider.java:1361)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.openAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:614)
    at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:284)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1375) 
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1311) 

Is there any way to fix this?

Do you see any error or anything in the log?

@tomerpacific actually I do see a log entry coming from Dropbox, I edited the question

Per the log, did you check the path?

@tomerpacific the URI looks like this: "content://com.dropbox.product.android.dbapp.document_provider.documents/document/..."
